# Where are MillerCoors Light Home Draft units available?

Tags: equipment, bottling, kegging, alternatives

MillerCoors used to sell Coors Light Home Draft and Miller Light Home Draft "kegs" at my local grocery store, but I have not seem them in a long time.

[image: MHD Photo]

The reason I ask is because these units are very similar to the Tap-A-Draft, which is designed for local brewery take-home as well as for home brewers.

[image: TAD Photo]

If you can find a way to get rid of the Miller or Coors beer, it's a much better deal to just buy the full one at the grocery store for $18, since a tap and empty bottle at the home brew store is $43 plus shipping.  But alas, they have disappeared from stores in Charlotte, NC.

I think that in at least selected areas, distributors report the MillerCoors product has been discontinued.  But the product still shows on the Wal-Mart site, and shows on the MillerCoors "Innovation" page.

Does anyone live near a store that still carries these?

Comment: Dale - it's very well presented but I'm not sure it's a good question. You want to find where this item is available. I can tell you that it's not available in Norway. Even in the US if someone tells you it's available 1000 miles away, will that really help?

Comment: I travel, so anywhere in the US would be helpful to me. Also, the question may help inform a home brewer that wanted an alternative to bottling; it may not have been obvious walking past this item in the grocery store that it could be re-used for home brew.

Comment: Travelling, ok, that's fair enough. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The product is no longer available:

```
Subject:    Regarding Case #:22090857 
Date:   29 Jul 2014 11:08:38 -0400
From:   Coors Light Online <CoorsLightOnline@CASupport.com>
To:     


Thank you for contacting MillerCoors.

Unfortunately, Coors Light Home Draft was discontinued due to lack of consumer demand. 
Sales simply did not warrant production. It was good of you to share your interest in this 
product and perhaps you may be interested in trying another MillerCoors brand.

We appreciate your interest in our products.

Sincerely,

MillerCoors Consumer Affairs Department
Ref: Case#N22090857
```

Answer (score 5):

Dallas, Texas; San Diego, California; Jacksonville, Florida; Phoenix, Arizona; Denver, Colorado and Columbus, Ohio.

Here is their website on it: http://www.coorslight.com/innovations/homedraft.aspx

They are currently only in test markets. You can find out more info on their Facebook page. http://www.facebook.com/pages/Coors-Light-Home-Draft/120696661275064

I actually found a Facebook app to locate them. http://apps.facebook.com/homedraftlocator/

Comment: impressive find!

Comment: but the facebook link seems to be unavailable now.

Comment: Awesome.  The second link tells me that they have them at some grocery stores around here!  I can't believe it.  I've been into 4 or 5 grocery stores and haven't seen them.

Comment: This worked for the first link:https://www.facebook.com/pages/Coors-Light-Home-Draft/120696661275064?ref=ts&fref=ts

Comment: The finder app is wrong (says they are in Charlotte, NC), but I know on my next trip though Jacksonville, I will be stopping to get some.